# Rails 3 : Specify inner join criteria "ON" in the rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inner-join, has-and-belongs-to-many

I want to access the table "Words" from the "linked_to" column, and not from "id" column.

The INNER JOIN query created by Rails always search for the id column in the Words table.

This is what I want to do :

- From the Class Point,
- Do an inner join to "linked_to" column (I already specify the :foreign_key)
- "Linked_to" is not unique in the "Words" table, because there is one line per translation
- Filter (Select) in the Words table, the value corresponding to my current language (let's assume dictionnary = 1)

[image: Table explanation for INNER JOIN]

My current Model

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :points, :foreign_key => "linked_to"    
  belongs_to :dictionnary 
  attr_accessible :lang, :value, :dictionnary_id, :language_id, :linked_to
end

class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :words, :association_foreign_key => "linked_to"     
    belongs_to :priority        
    attr_accessible :edited_by
end
```

Comment: In the Ruby console : irb(main):002:0> p.words
?[1m?[36mWord Load (0.0ms)?[0m
?[1mSELECT "words".* FROM "words" INNER JOIN "points_words" ON "words"."id" = "points_words"."linked_to" WHERE "points_words". "point_id" = 1?[0m

--> but I want "ON words.linked_to = ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called convention. :) You have created the wrong associations, beginning with your design.

The has_and_belongs_to_many creates a relation between two models, thus using their primary key. Rethink your models: the dictionary_id field does not belong to Words, but is a additional field for the intermediate table. When you 'qualify'  the intermediate table, you cannot use HASB anymore. Use a normal intermediate table

```
WordPointsForDictionary:
belongs_to :word
belongs_to :point
belongs_to :dictionary

Word:
has_many :points, :through => :WordPointsForDictionary
has_many :wordpointsfordictionary

Point:
has_many :words, :through => :WordPointsForDictionary
has_many :wordpointsfordictionary
```

This way you have removed the repetition and ugly relationships from you models. Clean primary key relationships and that will help you on the long way very much.

Comment: Thank you. Is "though" = ":through" ?

Comment: This solution seems awesome great :-) I'll work on it from now !

Comment: How can I have multiple word with the same id ? If I do like you propose, all words will have different id, and I can't change from one language to another for on especified Point. How do you select the words in another language from the Point class ? @Point.words.where("dictionnary = ?", 2)

Comment: The "value" field belongs to the WordPointsForDictionary class. Prevent duplicity in the Words class. The value field means: for a given word, in translation x, the translation is ...